# Charts doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I trying to use Chart.js in my web, but the chart won't appear and there's no error code in chrome console. I'm using Chart.js v2.7.2.

I tried any solution but doesn't help me, i also copy the code from chart.js documentation. what's wrong?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I've converted your code into an executable snippet and as you can see, it works as expected and prints a chart with two columns.

Comment: sorry, i dont know why, the code is works in snippet, but in my web it doesn't. i use codeigniter and put these code in view (home/index.php). the page won't show any chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "light1", // "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
    animationEnabled: false, // change to true      
    title:{
        text: "Basic Column Chart"
    },
    data: [
    {
        // Change type to "bar", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
            { label: "orange", y: 15  },
            { label: "banana", y: 25  },
            { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
            { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
        ]
    }
    ]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should TO use a different library when his approach with Chartjs works? o.O